# Checking sudoku solution (reading matrix from file) Python

Tags: sudoku

Need to make a program that reads the matrix from a .txt file and checks if the sudoku is solved correctly. The .txt file name is inserted in the command line. Has to return either True or False.

The sudoku checking part works, but there is a trouble with reading matrix from a file that is inserted in the command line.

Comment: See [`numpy.loadtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html).

Comment: what trouble? please post your code